# How to bypass (or disable) a command's "advice"?

Tags: advice

In my `.emacs` I have an expression of the form

```
(defadvice find-file ...)
```

...which modifies the behavior of the standard `find-file` command.

There are times, however, when I want to bypass this customized behavior altogether, and run the original, unmodified, `find-file`.

The only way I have found to do this is to comment-out the `(defadvice find-file ...)` expression in my `.emacs` file and start a fresh Emacs session.  This is an extremely disruptive, not to mention heavy-handed, solution.

Is there a way to tell Emacs to run the original `find-file`?

Alternatively, is there at least a way to rescind the `defadvice` altogether for the remainder of the Emacs session?

---

EDIT:
An earlier attempt to try something like what PythonNut suggests in a comment failed because I could not figure out how to write a simple wrapper for `find-file`.  More specifically, I replaced the `(defadvice find-file ...)` expression in my `.emacs` file with

```
(defun my-find-file (&rest args)
  (apply 'find-file args))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'my-find-file)

(defadvice my-find-file ...)
```

...where the code shown as `...` in the new `(defadvice my-find-file ...)` is identical to the `...` in the original `(defadvice find-file ...)`.

If I start a new Emacs session with this new `.emacs` file, and type `C-x C-f`, I get the error message `Wrong type argument: commandp, my-find-file`.  It looks like `my-find-file` is not an adequate wrapper for `find-file`.  (I posted a [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19215/882) specifically about this.)

Comment: Might I propose that creating a new `my-find-file` and using that instead of the regular `find-file` and switching back when you need the old behavior may be a better solution?

Comment: @PythonNut: please see my EDIT

Comment: what I really meant was to remove the `defadvice` entirely and put whatever modifications you made in the advice into your wrapper function.

Answer (score 7):

The `defadvice` macro is almost obsolete, having been replaced by an improved system that uses `advice-add`, `advice-remove`, etc, which allows you to turn advice on and off, among other things. See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) for details.

If you are stuck on an older version of Emacs without the improved system, you can deactivate advice on a function with `(ad-deactivate FUNCTION)`.

Comment: Won't that disable all advice for that function?

Comment: @PythonNut yes, `ad-deactivate` will allow you to run the "original, unmodified function", as requested by OP. If you want to add or remove individual pieces of advice, the `advice-add` and `advice-remove` functions allow for that too.

Answer (score 5):

If you have an Emacs version prior to release 24.4 then you have the doc for `defadvice' available from within Emacs.  In that case, **Ask Emacs!**

`C-h i` to open Info, the doc browser, in Emacs. Then choose the Elisp manual.  Then `i advice TAB` to look up advice in the index.

The `TAB` shows you the index entries that start with `advice`, one of which is `advice, enabling and disabling`. so continue typing: `, enab` and hit `RET` (Enter key) to visit the part of the manual (node ) that tells you the answer.

One answer is... command `ad-disable-advice`:

**`M-x ad-disable-advice RET find-file`**

But reading more you see that this disables a particular piece of advice of a particular class for the given function.  You can also *deactivate* **all** advice for the function.  Reading more, you come across command `ad-deactivate`, which does that:

**`M-x ad-deactivate RET find-file`**

Comment: Well, I had done that, but since none of the things I found in the docs worked (including all the suggestions you posted), I figured that I did not understand the Emacs documentation, and therefore posted my question...  When I say that these suggestions did not work, what I mean is that after doing them, `find-file` still does not work the way it does "out-of-the-box".

Comment: In that case, describe what you tried, step by step, and say what you saw and what you expected to see instead. You probably want to disable only one kind of advice defined for `find-file`, and you need to find the right one (look at the `defadvice` form to see what that is).

Comment: Note that after disabling a piece of advice with `(ad-disable-advice FUNCTION CLASS NAME)` -- or indeed enabling one with `(ad-enable-advice FUNCTION CLASS NAME)` -- you must then `(ad-activate FUNCTION)` for the change to take effect.

Comment: There is also `ad-remove-advice`. Both are available interactively.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with PythonNut that the best solution is probably not to use advice at all, but to define a new command `my-find-file` instead.

This said, if you find that advising `find-file` is a better option (e.g. because you also want to affect pre-exisitng calls to `find-file`), you might like to do it as follows:

```
(define-minor-mode my-find-file-mode
  "Tweak `find-file' the way I like it."
  :global t :init-value t)

(defun my-find-file-advice (orig &rest args)
  (if (not my-find-file-mode)
      (apply orig args)
    ..do the advice thing here..))
(advice-add 'find-file :around #'my-find-file-advice)
```

After which you can enable/disable your advice via `M-x my-find-file-mode`.